# How to run function in different runspace, PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have powershell script that add registration to event, but when the event is jump i'm getting the following error every time the event is jump:
"no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread" 
I'm using PS v2, what can i do?
Can you provide some code?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're trying to run script on a non-powershell thread, probably via an async callback. This is not a supported scenario. The trick is to "bridge" to callback to the eventing infrastructure, where scriptblocks haev a default runspace. Take a look at what I wrote here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190222052659/http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2009/10/09/PowerShell20AsynchronousCallbacksFromNET

It shows you how to work with async threads in powershell and run script in response to callbacks.

-Oisin

Answer (score 5):

Are you in a third party PowerShell host?  That's a bug ;)

If you're messing around with Async callbacks, the problem is that you're running in a different thread, and the `[Runspace]::DefaultRunspace` is thread static. @x0n wrote a bridge for Async Callbacks awhile back (I'll see if I can find it).

Bottom line, you need to do what the error suggests: provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type.  But you have to do it FROM the thread where the code is going to execute, so it's a bit rough with async callbacks.

```
[Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]::DefaultRunspace = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
```